# java.util.Calendar - necessary to set both HOUR and HOUR_OF_DAY?

Tags: java, calendar

I was reading through the [date4j homepage](http://date4j.net) and when talking about the problems with Java's `Calendar` class, it states the following:

> Calendar has two items referring to the hour of the day, HOUR and HOUR_OF_DAY. If, for example, you need to set the time portion of a Calendar object to 0, then you must set both the HOUR and HOUR_OF_DAY.

But whenever I need to reset a Calendar object back to, say, midnight, I never set *both* HOUR and HOUR_OF_DAY to 0, just HOUR_OF_DAY. And I've never had any issues with this.

Have I been doing this wrong all this time?

If someone could shed some light on what the above quote actually means I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the Calendar.HOUR, then you also have to set the Calendar.AM_PM field.  You cannot simply set the hour to 9 and believe you have set it to 9pm.  This would appear to work when run in the evening but not in the morning, when being set from a copy of the current time.

I think the comment is relating an experience about how setting the Calendar.HOUR was not good enough, and so they also set the Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, which fixed their Calendar.HOUR problem.  But the comment itself is not entirely accurate.

The Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY is not as ambiguous.  Setting HOUR_OF_DAY to 21 makes it 9pm.

Comment: I thought that that *might* be what they were referring to, but when you read the comment they clearly state that when setting the time back to 0 you have to set both HOUR and HOUR_OF_DAY to 0.

Comment: Docs as of Java 7 clarify this as not necessary: If HOUR_OF_DAY is the most recent field set, then it takes precedence over "AM_PM + HOUR". http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#time_resolution  "If there is any conflict in calendar field values, Calendar gives priorities to calendar fields that have been set more recently". Then it goes on to specifically show HOUR_OF_DAY vs "AM_PM + HOUR".

Answer (score 1):

They are very simple and there is nothing to be confused about.

`HOUR` is for 12-hour clock, that is why you have to set the `AM` or `PM` to indicate if it is daylight or noon.

`HOUR_OF_DAY` is a 24-hour clock, so you dont have to set the `AM` or `PM` field.

The statement that site made about a `MUST` is just not completely right